# Solution to Nonlinear ODE $s''( t) s( t) =( s'( t))^{2} +B( s( t))^{2} s'( t) -g\cdot s( t) s'( t)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I've solved linear ODEs before.  This however is something completely new to me.  I want to solve it without using approximations or anything.

$s''( t) s( t) =( s'( t))^{2} +B( s( t))^{2} s'( t) -g\cdot s( t) s'( t)$

These are the equations I started with

$ \begin{array}{l}
s'( t) =-Bs( t) i( t)\\
r'( t) =g\cdot i( t)\\
i'( t) =i( t)( Bs( t) -g)
\end{array}$

The reason I'm solving this particular equation is because I want to solve for all of the functions $(i(t),r(t),s(t))$  from above.

I just figured $s(t)$ might be the place to start.  I really don't have any clue where to start here.  Any help would be awesome!  Thanks!

--edit--
I made a mistake above.  In order to fix it I changed $i'( t) =i( t)( Bs( t) -1)$  to this $i'( t) =i( t)( Bs( t) -g)$.  My bad...

---Edit---

I might have a step towards the answer.

$ \begin{array}{l}
v( s) =s'( t)\\
\Longrightarrow \\
s''( t) =\frac{dv( s)}{dt} =\frac{dv}{ds}\frac{ds}{dt} =v'( s) \cdot \frac{ds}{dt} =v'( s) \cdot v( s)\\
\Longrightarrow \\
v'( s) \cdot v( s) s=v( t)^{2} +Bs^{2} v( t) -g\cdot s\cdot v( t)\\
\Longrightarrow \\
v'( s) \cdot s=v( t) +Bs^{2} -g\cdot s
\end{array}$

Wolfram Alpha says that the solution to this differential equation is

$v(s)=Bs^2+c_1s-gsln(s)$

So that means that

$s'(t)=Bs(t)^2+c_1s(t)-gs(t)\ln(s(t))$

This is certainly better than before

Comment: Autonomous equation: let $v(s)=s'(t)$. The resulting first order equation for $v$ may solved using an integrating factor. The result is integrated again to find $t(s)$. The solution to your equation is the inverse $s(t)$ which is not likely to be found in closed form

Comment: There are no completely closed-form solutions to the SIR - "zombie apocalypse" system. You can solve $\frac{d i}{d s}=\frac{i'}{s'}=\frac{Bs-1}{Bs}$ to get a first integral. With the correct constants you would also get $s+i+r=const.$, but that would here require that the last equation were $i'=i(Bs-g)$

Comment: Oh my bad,  it should be that, I forgot the g term somehow.

Comment: @Sal  Thanks Sal, that worked.  I posted the process as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me and my friend got it! (This was also exactly what Sal in the comments suggested doing)
$ \begin{array}{l}
v( s) =s'( t) \Longrightarrow \\
\frac{dv( s)}{dt} =\frac{dv( s)}{ds} \cdot \frac{ds}{dt} =v'( s) \cdot v( s) \ \text{literally the chain rule}\\
\Longrightarrow \\
v'( s) \cdot v( s) \cdot s=v( s)^{2} +Bs^{2} v( s) -gv( s) s\\
\\
\therefore v'( s) s=v( s) +Bs^{2} -gs
\end{array}$

Next find an integrating factor.

$ \begin{array}{l}
v'( s) -\frac{v( s)}{s} =Bs-g\\
integrating\ factor\ I=e^{\int \frac{1}{s} ds} =\frac{1}{s}
\end{array}$

Multiply both sides of the equation by the integrating factor.

$Iv'( s) -I\frac{1}{s} v( s) =I( Bs-g)$

The really interesting thing that makes this work is $\frac{d} {ds}(Iv(s))=Iv'(s)-I\frac{1}{s}v(s)$

$ \begin{array}{l}
\therefore \frac{d( Iv( s))}{dt} =I( Bs-g)\\
\Longrightarrow \\
Iv( s) =\int I( Bs-g) ds=\int \left( B-\frac{g}{s}\right) ds=Bs-ln( s) +c_{1}
\end{array}$

So we get

$v( s) =Bs^{2} +c_{1} s-gsln( s) \Longrightarrow
s'( t) =Bs( t)^{2} +c_{1} s( t) -gs( t) ln( s( t))$

Next just split the derivative and integrate

$1dt=\frac{1}{Bs( t)^{2} +c_{1} s( t) -gs( t) ln( s( t))} ds \Longrightarrow t+c_{2} =\int \frac{1}{Bs( t)^{2} +c_{1} s( t) -gs( t) ln( s( t))} ds$

Solving for the constants we get

$ \begin{array}{l}
at\ t=0\\
s'( 0) =Bs( 0)^{2} +c_{1} s( 0) -gs( 0) ln( s( 0))\\
and\ we\ know\ that\ s'( t) =-Bs( t) i( t)\\
\\
s'( 0) =-Bs( 0) i( 0)\\
\Longrightarrow \\
-Bs_{0} i_{0} =Bs_{0}^{2} +c_{1} s_{0} -gs_{0} ln( s_{0})\\
\Longrightarrow \\
c_{1} =gln( s_{0}) +B( s_{0} -i_{0})\\
c_{2} =\int _{0}^{s( 0)}\frac{1}{B\omega ^{2} +c_{1} \omega -g\omega ln( \omega )} d\omega =\int _{0}^{s_{0}}\frac{1}{B\omega ^{2} +( gln( s_{0}) +B( s_{0} -i_{0})) \omega -g\omega ln( \omega )} d\omega \\
\\
\therefore t=\\
\int\limits _{0}^{s( t)}\frac{1}{B\omega ^{2} +( gln( s_{0}) +B( s_{0} -i_{0})) \omega -g\omega ln( \omega )} d\omega -\int\limits _{0}^{s_{0}}\frac{1}{B\omega ^{2} +( gln( s_{0}) +B( s_{0} -i_{0})) \omega -g\omega ln( \omega )} d\omega 
\end{array}$

We can combine the integrals because of their limits

$t=\int _{s_{0}}^{s( t)}\frac{1}{B\omega ^{2} +( gln( s_{0}) +B[ s_{0} -i_{0}]) \omega -g\omega ln( \omega )} d\omega $

Desmos graphs this in its current form, but if you wanted $s(t)=$something then the Lagrange Inversion theorem probably works here.
[image]

Edit...  I was actually able to graph all three functions for the SIR model in desmos (green equation is s(t), red i(t) blue r(t)) [desmos graph for SIR model](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tpqrs9kcnc)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Making $y = \int s dt$ we have

$$
\frac{y'''}{y''}=\frac{y''}{y'}+B y'-g
$$

then

$$
\ln\left(\frac{y''}{y'}\right)=B y - g t+C
$$

or

$$
y''=y'C_1e^{By-gt}
$$
This last ODE has an implicit closed solution under Wolfram.